# Fetching data between 2 underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
Declare @t nvarchar(300) ='83082351_10_P00004'

select SUBSTRING(
                    @t,
                    charindex('_',@t)+1,
                    CHARINDEX('_', @t, (CHARINDEX('_', @t)+1))
)
```

I want the output as `10` which is between the two `_` characters, I don't know what I am doing wrong in my query.

Can someone please help me in this.

Comment: `SUBSTRING` returns the number of characters defined by the 3rd parameter, and in that position you're returning  the **position** of the 2nd underscore, which is `12`; so you're asking for the 12 characters *after* the first underscore.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larnu pointed out, you are asking for too many characters.  You need to also subtract the position of the initial underscore to return just the middle characters:

```
declare @t nvarchar(300) ='83082351_10_P00004'

select substring(@t
                ,charindex('_',@t)+1
                ,charindex('_'
                          ,@t
                          ,charindex('_', @t)+1
                          )
                 - (charindex('_',@t)+1)
                )
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (charindex('_', @t)...` saves you having to write it out 3 times